# How to convert a V4 study code to V5 to add it to an indicator?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have an indicator I built running on V5 pinescript and I want to add this one which is written in V4 pinescript:

```
//@version=4
study("Tweezer and Kangaroo Tail", overlay = true)
enable_tweezer = input(defval = true, title = "Enable Tweezer")
maxrate = input(defval = 150., title = "Max Rate % Between Wick Sizes") / 100.
leveldiff = input(defval = 20., title = "Max Difference in level %") / 100.
prd =input(defval = 5, title = "Highest/Lowest Period")
apartprd = input(defval = 12, title = "Max Distance between Tweezers", minval = 1)
colup = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Color", inline = "col")
coldn = input(defval = color.red, title = "", inline = "col")


topwick = high - max(close, open)
bottomwick = min(close, open) - low
body = abs(close - open)
ishb = highestbars(prd) == 0
islb = lowestbars(prd) == 0
aparttweezers_top(len)=>
    ret = 0
    if topwick > 0
        for x = 1 to apartprd
            if nz(topwick[x]) == 0
                break
            if (max(topwick, topwick[x]) / min(topwick, topwick[x])) <= maxrate and abs(high - high[x]) < max(topwick, topwick[x]) * leveldiff and ishb[x]
                ret := x
                break
            else 
                if high[x] >= high
                    ret := 0
                    break
    ret
    
aparttweezers_bottom(len)=>
    ret = 0
    if bottomwick > 0
        for x = 1 to apartprd
            if nz(bottomwick[x]) == 0
                break
            if (max(bottomwick, bottomwick[x]) / min(bottomwick, bottomwick[x])) <= maxrate and abs(low - low[x]) < max(bottomwick, bottomwick[x]) * leveldiff and islb[x]
                ret := x
                break
            else 
                if low[x] <= low
                    ret := 0
                    break
    ret

top_tweezer = enable_tweezer and aparttweezers_top(apartprd)
bottom_tweezer = enable_tweezer and aparttweezers_bottom(apartprd)
plotshape(top_tweezer, text = "T", style = shape.labeldown, location =  location.abovebar, color = coldn, textcolor = color.white)
plotshape(bottom_tweezer, text = "T", style = shape.labelup, location =  location.belowbar, color = colup, textcolor = color.black)

// KANGAROO TAIL 
enable_kangaroo_tail = input(defval = true, title = "Enable Kangaroo Tail")
prd1 = input(defval = 20, title="Period for Room", minval = 2, maxval = 50)
prd2 = input(defval = 8, title="Minimum Period for Room", minval = 2, maxval = 50)
atrmult = input(defval = 5, title="ATR Factor for Room Height", minval = 2, maxval = 30)
wickmult = input(defval = 3., title = "Wick/Body Rate", minval = 1)
wickmultavg = input(defval = 2., title = "Wick/Average_Wick Rate", minval = 1)

float ph = highestbars(high, prd1) == 0 ? high : na
float pl = lowestbars(low, prd1) == 0 ? low : na
var dir = 0
dir := iff(ph and na(pl), 1, iff(pl and na(ph), -1, dir))
var max_array_size = 4
var zigzag = array.new_float(4, 0.)

add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)=>
    array.unshift(zigzag, bindex)
    array.unshift(zigzag, value)
    array.pop(zigzag)
    array.pop(zigzag)
    
update_zigzag(value, bindex)=>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)
    else
        if (dir == 1 and value > array.get(zigzag, 0)) or (dir == -1 and value < array.get(zigzag, 0))
            array.set(zigzag, 0, value)
            array.set(zigzag, 1, bindex)
        0.

dirchanged = change(dir)
if ph or pl
    if dirchanged
        add_to_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)

averagetopwicksize = sma(topwick, 50)

topkangaroo = enable_kangaroo_tail and dir == 1  and topwick >= body * wickmult and close <= low + (high - low) / 3 and open <= low + (high - low) / 3 and 
  open < high[1] and open > low[1] and close < high[1] and close > low[1] and topwick >= wickmultavg * averagetopwicksize and body > 0 and
  ph and array.get(zigzag, 0) == high and array.get(zigzag, 0) - array.get(zigzag, 2) > atr(50) * atrmult and array.get(zigzag, 1) - array.get(zigzag, 3) > prd2

bottomkangaroo = enable_kangaroo_tail and dir == -1  and bottomwick >= body * wickmult and close >= high - (high - low) / 3 and open >= high - (high - low) / 3 and 
  open < high[1] and open > low[1] and close < high[1] and close > low[1] and bottomwick >= wickmultavg * averagetopwicksize and body > 0 and
  pl and array.get(zigzag, 0) == low and array.get(zigzag, 2) - array.get(zigzag, 0) > atr(50) * atrmult and array.get(zigzag, 1) - array.get(zigzag, 3) > prd2

plotshape(topkangaroo, text = "K", style = shape.labeldown, location =  location.abovebar, color = coldn, textcolor = color.white)
plotshape(bottomkangaroo, text = "K", style = shape.labelup, location =  location.belowbar, color = colup, textcolor = color.black)

alertcondition(topkangaroo, title='Kangaroo Tail Bearish', message='Kangaroo Tail Bearish')
alertcondition(bottomkangaroo, title='Kangaroo Tail Bullish', message='Kangaroo Tail Bullish')
alertcondition(top_tweezer, title='Tweezers Bearish', message='Tweezers Bearish')
alertcondition(bottom_tweezer, title='Tweezers Bullish', message='Tweezers Bullish')
```

Would it be possible to convert it? I tried to delete the study line, but it gave me this error:

line 266: The arguments 'maxval', 'minval', and 'step' cannot be used with the input() function. You can use the input.int() or input.float() functions to specify a range of input data values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the auto converter tool from the menu (three dots right next to the "*Publish script*" button.

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator('Tweezer and Kangaroo Tail', overlay=true)
enable_tweezer = input(defval=true, title='Enable Tweezer')
maxrate = input(defval=150., title='Max Rate % Between Wick Sizes') / 100.
leveldiff = input(defval=20., title='Max Difference in level %') / 100.
prd = input(defval=5, title='Highest/Lowest Period')
apartprd = input.int(defval=12, title='Max Distance between Tweezers', minval=1)
colup = input.color(defval=color.lime, title='Color', inline='col')
coldn = input.color(defval=color.red, title='', inline='col')


topwick = high - math.max(close, open)
bottomwick = math.min(close, open) - low
body = math.abs(close - open)
ishb = ta.highestbars(prd) == 0
islb = ta.lowestbars(prd) == 0
aparttweezers_top(len) =>
    ret = 0
    if topwick > 0
        for x = 1 to apartprd by 1
            if nz(topwick[x]) == 0
                break
            if math.max(topwick, topwick[x]) / math.min(topwick, topwick[x]) <= maxrate and math.abs(high - high[x]) < math.max(topwick, topwick[x]) * leveldiff and ishb[x]
                ret := x
                break
            else
                if high[x] >= high
                    ret := 0
                    break
    ret

aparttweezers_bottom(len) =>
    ret = 0
    if bottomwick > 0
        for x = 1 to apartprd by 1
            if nz(bottomwick[x]) == 0
                break
            if math.max(bottomwick, bottomwick[x]) / math.min(bottomwick, bottomwick[x]) <= maxrate and math.abs(low - low[x]) < math.max(bottomwick, bottomwick[x]) * leveldiff and islb[x]
                ret := x
                break
            else
                if low[x] <= low
                    ret := 0
                    break
    ret

top_tweezer = enable_tweezer and aparttweezers_top(apartprd)
bottom_tweezer = enable_tweezer and aparttweezers_bottom(apartprd)
plotshape(top_tweezer, text='T', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=coldn, textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(bottom_tweezer, text='T', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=colup, textcolor=color.new(color.black, 0))

// KANGAROO TAIL 
enable_kangaroo_tail = input(defval=true, title='Enable Kangaroo Tail')
prd1 = input.int(defval=20, title='Period for Room', minval=2, maxval=50)
prd2 = input.int(defval=8, title='Minimum Period for Room', minval=2, maxval=50)
atrmult = input.int(defval=5, title='ATR Factor for Room Height', minval=2, maxval=30)
wickmult = input.float(defval=3., title='Wick/Body Rate', minval=1)
wickmultavg = input.float(defval=2., title='Wick/Average_Wick Rate', minval=1)

float ph = ta.highestbars(high, prd1) == 0 ? high : na
float pl = ta.lowestbars(low, prd1) == 0 ? low : na
var dir = 0
iff_1 = pl and na(ph) ? -1 : dir
dir := ph and na(pl) ? 1 : iff_1
var max_array_size = 4
var zigzag = array.new_float(4, 0.)

add_to_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    array.unshift(zigzag, bindex)
    array.unshift(zigzag, value)
    array.pop(zigzag)
    array.pop(zigzag)

update_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)
    else
        if dir == 1 and value > array.get(zigzag, 0) or dir == -1 and value < array.get(zigzag, 0)
            array.set(zigzag, 0, value)
            array.set(zigzag, 1, bindex)
        0.

dirchanged = ta.change(dir)
if ph or pl
    if dirchanged
        add_to_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)

averagetopwicksize = ta.sma(topwick, 50)

topkangaroo = enable_kangaroo_tail and dir == 1 and topwick >= body * wickmult and close <= low + (high - low) / 3 and open <= low + (high - low) / 3 and open < high[1] and open > low[1] and close < high[1] and close > low[1] and topwick >= wickmultavg * averagetopwicksize and body > 0 and ph and array.get(zigzag, 0) == high and array.get(zigzag, 0) - array.get(zigzag, 2) > ta.atr(50) * atrmult and array.get(zigzag, 1) - array.get(zigzag, 3) > prd2

bottomkangaroo = enable_kangaroo_tail and dir == -1 and bottomwick >= body * wickmult and close >= high - (high - low) / 3 and open >= high - (high - low) / 3 and open < high[1] and open > low[1] and close < high[1] and close > low[1] and bottomwick >= wickmultavg * averagetopwicksize and body > 0 and pl and array.get(zigzag, 0) == low and array.get(zigzag, 2) - array.get(zigzag, 0) > ta.atr(50) * atrmult and array.get(zigzag, 1) - array.get(zigzag, 3) > prd2

plotshape(topkangaroo, text='K', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=coldn, textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(bottomkangaroo, text='K', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=colup, textcolor=color.new(color.black, 0))

alertcondition(topkangaroo, title='Kangaroo Tail Bearish', message='Kangaroo Tail Bearish')
alertcondition(bottomkangaroo, title='Kangaroo Tail Bullish', message='Kangaroo Tail Bullish')
alertcondition(top_tweezer, title='Tweezers Bearish', message='Tweezers Bearish')
alertcondition(bottom_tweezer, title='Tweezers Bullish', message='Tweezers Bullish')
```